# Deriving a trivial Eq class from a GADT

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

I thought GADTs were great until I tried putting any of the "expressions with GADTs" examples scattered around the internet to use.

Traditional ADTs kindly provide definitional equality in the guise of Eq for free. In GADTs for this code:

```
data Expr a where
  (:+:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  (:-:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  (:*:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  (:/:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  (:=:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  (:<:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  (:>:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  (:>=:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  (:<=:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  (:<>:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  EOr :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  EAnd :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  ENot :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  ESymbol :: (Show a, Eq a) => String -> Expr a
  ELiteral :: (Show a, Eq a) => a -> Expr a
  EFunction :: (Show a, Eq a) => String -> [Expr a] -> Expr a
  deriving (Eq)
```

I get (very understandably):

```
    • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Eq (Expr a)’:
        Constructor ‘:+:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:-:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:*:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:/:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:=:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:<:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:>:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:>=:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:<=:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘:<>:’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘EOr’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘EAnd’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘ENot’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘ESymbol’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘ELiteral’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Constructor ‘EFunction’ has existentials or constraints in its type
        Possible fix: use a standalone deriving declaration instead
    • In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
```

Which would be understandable if I hadn't the `Eq` restriction for each constructor but now I have to write trivial equality rules for all these constructors.

I feel like there is better way to go about this than I have

Comment: Why do you have all those constraints on the constructors in the first place?

Comment: I want to be able to get LaTeX representations with Show. Where should I have the constraints? Indeed now that I think of it the particular ones are not useful but I can't think of a way to do away with the existentials completely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traditional `deriving` can't handle GADT constraints. Standalone deriving can, in principle:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}
data Expr a where
  (:+:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  ...
deriving instance Eq (Expr a)
```

However, that doesn't help you because that `Eq` instance is just not possible. How will you compare

```
(1 :<: (2 :: Expr Int)) == (pi :<: (sqrt 2 :: Expr Double))
```

It's just not possible; the GADT constraint

```
  (:<:) :: (Show a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

only enforces that both values *compared in that `Expr`* have the same type and are `Eq`, but it doesn't tell you anything about the types of *different* expressions.

Comment: Well the way I am thinking of it is that the expressions you present above is obviously not equal because the left side of `:<:` is not the same, even though their evaluated value may be equal.

Comment: It just dawned on me what you are suggesting. You are right.

Comment: The way I am thinking is that this kind of `Eq` instance is in principle not a good idea, because there are all kinds of “obvious” properties of such expressions which don't actually hold.